# Off-chain DB indexing example

Tags: database, offchain, indexing

Where can I find `Tomasz Drwięga` Off-chain DB indexing example, implementing the following runtime function?

```
fn on_finalize(_n: BlockNumberFor<T>){}
```

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out it's just a `hook`, so no worries, all good.

```
#[pallet::hooks]
impl<T: Config> Hooks<BlockNumberFor<T>> for Pallet<T> {
    /// Initialization
    fn on_initialize(now: BlockNumberFor<T>) -> Weight {
        Self::do_initialize(now);
        0
    }

    /// Block finalization
    fn on_finalize(_n: BlockNumberFor<T>) {
        // at the end of the block, we can safely include the new VRF output
        // from this block into the under-construction randomness. If we've determined
        // that this block was the first in a new epoch, the changeover logic has
        // already occurred at this point, so the under-construction randomness
        // will only contain outputs from the right epoch.
        if let Some(Some(randomness)) = Initialized::<T>::take() {
            Self::deposit_randomness(&randomness);
        }

        // remove temporary "environment" entry from storage
        Lateness::<T>::kill();
    }
}
```